# re-programming a semi-advanced rounding program

Tags: r, function, rounding

Hi all: I have a question related to a previous post about a rounding program (available here:  [R: Round the contents within each row so that the row total is equal to a number I specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829504/r-round-the-contents-within-each-row-so-that-the-row-total-is-equal-to-a-number)).

The program is designed to round the contents within each row so that the row total is equal to a number I specify. Copied from the original post, here is a MWE that works:

```
Round <- function(x, target) {
r.x <- round(x)
diff.x <- round(x) - x
if ((s <- sum(r.x)) == target) {
return(r.x)
} else if (s > target) {
select <- seq(along=x)[diff.x > 0]
which <- which.max(diff.x[select])
x[select[which]] <- r.x[select[which]] - 1
Round(x, target)
} else {
select <- seq(along=x)[diff.x < 0]
which <- which.min(diff.x[select])
x[select[which]] <- r.x[select[which]] + 1
Round(x, target)
}
}

dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = paste0('place', 1:4),
              text="race1 race2 total
                    1.2  2.1  3.4
                    3.4  3.6  7.0
                    7.7  0.8  8.5
                    5.3  1.4  6.7")

totals <- c(4.0, 7.0, 8.0, 7.0)

do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) Round(dat[x, -3], totals[x])))

#        race1 race2
# place1     2     2
# place2     3     4
# place3     7     1
# place4     5     2
```

The problem is this: It has recently come to my attention that this function ceases to work if the number the row is supposed to be rounded to is greater or less than 1 away from the natural rounded total. So, in the above example, row 2 is naturally rounded to 3 and 4. If the total specified in the totals object is equal to 6 through 8 for row 2, the function works fine. But if the total the row is coerced to is less than 6 or greater than 8, the function no longer works.

To illustrate this example, the above 'Round' code no longer works if we change the totals values as follows:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = paste0('place', 1:4),
              text="race1 race2 total
                    1.2  2.1  3.4
                    3.4  3.6  7.0
                    7.7  0.8  8.5
                    5.3  1.4  6.7")

totals <- c(4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 7.0)

do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) Round(dat[x, -3], totals[x])))
Error in data.frame(value, row.names=rn, check.names = FALSE, check.rows
= FALSE) : 'row.names' should specify one of the variables
```

(Note the change in the totals object from c(4.0, 7.0,...) to c(4.0, 5.0,...))

What I need help with is altering the code so that the special Rounding function will still work if the row total the row is forced to be rounded to is, say, 4 away from the natural rounded total. (In some cases in my more advanced data.frame I have rows which need to be rounded to up to 14 digits away from the naturally rounded row total.)

**Updated Example**

Using a slightly altered code provided by rawr, I now get an error if the total I need the row to be rounded to is 3 or more away from the natural rounded total.

The updated code is as follows:

```
Round <- function(x, target){
 r.x <- round(x)
 diff.x <- round(x) - x
 if ((s <- sum(r.x)) == target) {return(r.x)
} else if (s > target) {
     select <- seq(along=x)[diff.x != 0]
     which <- which.max(diff.x[select])
     x[select[which]] <- r.x[select[which]] - 1
     Round(x, target)
 }
 else{
     select <- seq(along=x)[diff.x != 0]
     which <- which.min(diff.x[select])
     x[select[which]] <- r.x[select[which]] + 1
     Round(x, target)
 }
}
```

And here is the example that is producing an error:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = paste0('district', 1:4),
text="race1 race2 total
1.2 2.1 3.4
3.4 3.6 7.0
7.7 0.8 8.5
5.3 1.4 6.7")

totals <- c(4.0, 5.0, 12.0, 7.0)

do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) Round(dat[x, -3], totals[x])))

Error in data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE, check.rows = FALSE) : 
'row.names' should specify one of the variables
```

Comment: @rawr you were of great help last time!

Comment: I use a [slightly modified version](https://github.com/raredd/rawr/blob/master/R/zxx.R#L736-L752) of this which works for both examples the relevant difference being `diff.x != 0` in mine vs `diff.x > 0` in the q

Comment: Ok, now when I run the function and code I get an error when the total is 3 or more away from the natural rounded total. See updated example above

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug these is to take a few cases and step through the functions to figure out where the error is coming from.

This function seems intended to round decimals, not integers, to closest integer, so after rounding, eventually all `diff.x != 0` will be `FALSE` so `which.max` won't return anything.

I guess you could come up with a number of ways to select which values will be adjusted at each step, but below are two, each with pros/cons.

The first simply takes the min or max depending if the target is above or below the sum of the vector. The second randomly selects one of the vector elements weighted by its value. `set.seed` to make the results reproducible, but this introduces a little randomness into the equation. The first will keep increasing or decreasing the same value leading to skewed results

```
Round <- function(x, target) {
  r.x <- round(x)
  diff.x <- r.x - x
  if ((s <- sum(r.x)) == target) {
    return(r.x)
  } else if (s > target) {
    select <- seq_along(x)[diff.x != 0]
    select <- if (length(select)) select else which.max(x)
    wh <- which.max(diff.x[select])
    x[select[wh]] <- r.x[select[wh]] - 1
    Recall(x, target)
  } else {
    select <- seq_along(x)[diff.x != 0]
    select <- if (length(select)) select else which.min(x)
    wh <- which.min(diff.x[select])
    x[select[wh]] <- r.x[select[wh]] + 1
    Recall(x, target)
  }
}

Round2 <- function(x, target) {
  set.seed(1)
  r.x <- round(x)
  diff.x <- r.x - x
  if ((s <- sum(r.x)) == target) {
    return(r.x)
  } else if (s > target) {
    select <- seq_along(x)[diff.x != 0]
    # select <- if (length(select)) select else which.max(x)
    select <- if (length(select)) select else
      sample(seq_along(x), 1, prob = prop.table(x))
    wh <- which.max(diff.x[select])
    x[select[wh]] <- r.x[select[wh]] - 1
    Recall(x, target)
  } else {
    select <- seq_along(x)[diff.x != 0]
    # select <- if (length(select)) select else which.min(x)
    select <- if (length(select)) select else
      sample(seq_along(x), 1, prob = prop.table(x))
    wh <- which.min(diff.x[select])
    x[select[wh]] <- r.x[select[wh]] + 1
    Recall(x, target)
  }
}

dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = paste0('district', 1:4),
                    text="race1 race2 total
1.2 2.1 3.4
3.4 3.6 7.0
7.7 0.8 8.5
5.3 1.4 6.7")

totals <- c(4.0, 5.0, 12.0, 7.0)
```

This one will always give the same results but also keeps increasing the same value as in the second example where 7.7 is rounded to 9 and 0.8 is rounded to 8

```
cbind(
  dat,
  totals,
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) Round(dat[x, -3], totals[x])))
)

#           race1 race2 total totals race1 race2
# district1   1.2   2.1   3.4      4     2     2
# district2   3.4   3.6   7.0      5     2     3
# district3   7.7   0.8   8.5     12     9     3
# district4   5.3   1.4   6.7      7     5     2


cbind(dat[3, ], Round(dat[3, 1:2], 17))
#           race1 race2 total race1 race2
# district3   7.7   0.8   8.5     9     8
```

In this one, we set a seed to get the same results each time, but the sampling is less than ideal I guess, but now in the second example 7.7 is rounded to 15 and 0.8 to 2 which is closer to what I would expect.

```
cbind(
  dat,
  totals,
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) Round2(dat[x, -3], totals[x])))
)

#           race1 race2 total totals race1 race2
# district1   1.2   2.1   3.4      4     2     2
# district2   3.4   3.6   7.0      5     2     3
# district3   7.7   0.8   8.5     12    10     2
# district4   5.3   1.4   6.7      7     5     2

cbind(dat[3, ], Round2(dat[3, 1:2], 17))

#           race1 race2 total race1 race2
# district3   7.7   0.8   8.5    15     2
```